# Euler class of a vector bundle over sphere.

Tags: algebraic-topology

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0004147.pdf) paper on page 6, authors say that euler number of the $R^4$-bundle over $S^4$, denoted by $\xi_{m,n}$ is $n$. The description of $\xi_{m,n}$ is on page 1. I want to know how is the euler number $n$. I can not find anything related.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you define an oriented even dimensional vector bundle $\mathbb{R}^n \to E\to S^n$ over a sphere specifying the transition function on the equator
$$ S^{n-1} \longrightarrow SO(n),$$
then the Euler number is the degree of the composition
$$ S^{n-1} \longrightarrow SO(n) \longrightarrow S^{n-1}$$
where the second map is the projection $SO(n) \to S^n$ that takes a rotation to the image of the first vector of the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. In your case, the composition of $\sigma$ and the projection is easily seen to be the identity, and therefore the Euler number of the bundle defined by $\sigma$ is 1.

To see that the Euler number is the degree of the composition $f$ above, recall the definition of a vector bundle over a sphere by clutching, and observe that you can define a section of the bundle $E$ as follows:

- On the lower hemisphere send every point to the first standard vector. This defines a section of $S_-^n\times \mathbb{R}^n  \to S_-^n$.
- On the upper hemisphere send a point  $tx$ with $0\leq t \leq 1$ and $x\in S^{n-1}$ to $tf(x)$ (this is not smooth at the equator or the north pole, but can be smoothed using bump functions).

This defines a section of the bundle $E$ with an isolated zero at the north pole. The index of that zero is computed as the degree of the map $f$.